# Xcode 4.5.2 SIGKILL when changing calendar privacy for app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios6

I'm using the EventKit framework to get user's events and I'm also subscribing to `EKEventStoreChangedNotification` to get notified when the user's calendar changes. So I wanted to see what happens if the user turns off access for calendar in Privacy > Calendars. If the app will still receive `EKEventStoreChangedNotification` notifications but the app is `SIGKILL`ed.

Does anyone know if an app still receives `EKEventStoreChangedNotification` notifications for a once granted access to Calendar but subsequently denied access to calendar?